# Get pixel position of IMAGE WIDGET in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Below pasted is the code for getting pixel position. However, i intend to get only image pixel position whenever mouse is clicked. In present code it is working on whole window.

```
__version__ = '1.0'

import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Point, GraphicException
from random import random



class Touchtracer(FloatLayout):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        win = self.get_parent_window()
        ud = touch.ud
        ud['group'] = g = str(touch.uid)
        pointsize = 5
        if 'pressure' in touch.profile:
           ud['pressure'] = touch.pressure
           pointsize = (touch.pressure * 100000) ** 2
           ud['color'] = random()

        with self.canvas:
            Color(ud['color'], 1, 1, mode='hsv', group=g)
            ud['lines'] = [
            Rectangle(pos=(touch.x, 0), size=(1, win.height), group=g),
            Rectangle(pos=(0, touch.y), size=(win.width, 1), group=g),
            Point(points=(touch.x, touch.y), source='particle.png',
                  pointsize=pointsize, group=g)]

        ud['label'] = Label(size_hint=(None, None))
        self.update_touch_label(ud['label'], touch)
        self.add_widget(ud['label'])
        touch.grab(self)
        return True



    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return
        touch.ungrab(self)
        ud = touch.ud
        self.canvas.remove_group(ud['group'])
        self.remove_widget(ud['label'])

    def update_touch_label(self, label, touch):
        label.text = 'ID: %s\nPos: (%d, %d)\nClass: %s' % (
            touch.id, touch.x, touch.y, touch.__class__.__name__)
        label.texture_update()
        label.pos = touch.pos
        label.size = label.texture_size[0] + 20, label.texture_size[1] + 20


class TouchtracerApp(App):


    def build(self):
        return Touchtracer()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TouchtracerApp().run()
```

touchtracer.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import kivy kivy

<Touchtracer>:
    img:img
    Image:
    id: img

    source: 'image.jpg'

    size: 200,200
 BoxLayout:
    padding: '10dp'
    spacing: '10dp'
    size_hint: 1, None
    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    height: '44dp'
    Image:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: '24dp', '24dp'
        source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-64.png'
        mipmap: True
    Label:
        height: '24dp'
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: (1, 1, 1, .8)
        text: 'Kivy %s - Touchtracer' % kivy.__version__
        valign: 'middle'
```

How can i make it work only on Image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want to test for collision with the image widget before doing your calculation? If so, you can do the following:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if not self.img.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        return False
    # Put the rest of your code here, just like it already is
```

Comment: Yes you are right, however i think i have made some other mistake in my code which is not working even after adding this line.